# Killing fields of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

Is the euclidean space maximally symmetric? And if it does, what Are the  `1/2 n (n+1)= 3`killing fields? How can I have 3 linearly independent fields in R2? Maybe I am mixing some concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Euclidean space is maximally symmetric.

It is important to remember that the vector space of smooth vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is nowhere near the same as the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$. The space of all possible vector fields is much larger than the space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The three independent Killing vector fields correspond to three independent isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The symmetries are two translation symmetries and one rotation symmetry, making 3 total.

Comment: Thank you very much that was helpful... For some unknown reasons i thought those spaces were the same, or Maybe  isomorphic

Comment: @user199710 Solutions of $\nabla_a X_b+\nabla_b X_a=0$ live in a space of functions. Although those functions' values live in an $n$-dimensional space, the functions themselves live in a space of in general larger dimension.